# A triangle with angles $A,B,C$ and corresponding sides $a,b,c$. Given $\dfrac{2a+b}{c} = \dfrac{\cos(A+C)}{\cos C}$

Tags: trigonometry

There is a triangle, with angles $A,B,C$ and corresponding sides $a,b,c$. Given $\dfrac{2a+b}c=\dfrac{\cos(A+C)}{\cos C}$

Find angle $C$
If side $c=2$, find the maximum area of the triangle and find $a$,$b$

I tried law of cosines but couldn't figure out a solution. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe show what you did with law of cosines and we could find a mistake there.

Comment: It may be worth noting that $A+C=\pi-B$, so $\cos(A+C)=-\cos(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the law of cosines,
$$\begin{align}\frac{2a+b}{c}=\frac{\cos (A+C)}{\cos C}&\iff \frac{2a+b}{c}=\frac{\cos(\pi-B)}{\cos C}=-\frac{\cos B}{\cos C}\\&\iff \frac{2a+b}{c}=-\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\cdot\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2-c^2}\\&\iff (2a+b)(a^2+b^2-c^2)+b(a^2+c^2-b^2)=0\\&\iff 2a(a^2+ab+b^2-c^2)=0\\&\iff a^2+ab+b^2=c^2\end{align}$$

So, if $c=2$, then we have
$$a^2+ab+b^2=4$$
and so
$$\cos C=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=\frac{a^2+b^2-4}{2ab}=\frac{-ab}{2ab}=-\frac 12\quad\Rightarrow \quad \color{red}{C=\frac 23\pi}.$$

Now let $S$ be the area of $\triangle{ABC}$. Then,
$$S=\frac 12ab\sin C=\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}ab\tag1$$

By the way, by AM-GM inequality, we have
$$ab\le\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}=\frac{4+ab}{4}\quad\Rightarrow \quad ab\le\frac{4}{3}\tag2$$

It follows from $(1)(2)$ that the maximum area is $\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}}$ when $\color{red}{a=b=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2a+b)\cos C=c\cos(C+A)=c\cos(\pi-B)=-c\cos B$$

$$\iff2a\cos C=-(b\cos C+c\cos B)=-a$$

As $a\ne0,\cos C=-\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac{2\pi}3\implies C=2m\pi\pm\dfrac{2\pi}3$ where $m$ in any integer

As $0<C<\pi,C=\dfrac{2\pi}3\implies\sin C=\sin\dfrac{2\pi}3=\sin\left(\pi-\dfrac\pi3\right)=\sin\dfrac\pi3=\cdots$

$\implies A+B=\pi-\dfrac{2\pi}3=?$

If $c=2,2R=\dfrac c{\sin C}=\dfrac4{\sqrt3}$ which is constant

$\triangle ABC=\dfrac{abc}{4R}=R\cdot2\sin A\sin\left(\dfrac\pi3-A\right)=R\left[\cos\left(\dfrac\pi3-2A\right)-\cos\dfrac\pi3\right]$ which will be maximum if $\cos\left(\dfrac\pi3-2A\right)$ is maximum i.e., when $$\dfrac\pi3-2A=2n\pi$$ where $n$ in any integer

As $0<2A<2\pi,2A=\dfrac\pi3$

Can you take it from here?